# Django generic view redirect

Tags: django, redirect, django-generic-views

I have created a blog app using Django wherein Generic views are used to Add, Update and Delete a blog post. I want to know a method by which I could redirect to the same Blog page after creating it or updating it. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add `get_absolute_url` for your model, check [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/class-based-views/generic-editing/#model-forms)